# Why cant i access my google account on a new phone when I have not factory reset my old phone

Tags: google-account

I recently bought a LG Stylo 3. It is the EXACT same brand and model of my old phone.

I bought a used phone from Offerup but I know it is not locked. The person who sold me the phone did a factory reset to it right before selling it to me. I called Metro PCS and activated the newly bought phone.

I tried to sign in to my google account and i entered all the information correctly. but it tells me i have to wait 24 hours before attempting to sign in again.

I waited 24 hours and the same message prompted. I waited 72 hours and the same thing.

How can  I prove I am the owner of the Google account and allowed to use my new (used) phone?! I am frustrated because Google does not have a service to call or even text.

The phone is not locked, I have all the informations and I can still access my information easily on my old phone. Can I add a new device to my google account before activating it?

Essentially this is not an issue of a used or new phone, it is an issue with my Google account and thus if my old phone (that I am forced to use) breaks then I am completely screwed.

How does Google have a multi billion dollar business if they dont have customer service help??

Comment: Did you try logging in to your account from a computer instead? May be you have some security mechanisms enabled such as 2-factors auth and such...

Comment: I'm confused... You have your Google account credentials and can log into it on any device except this "new" phone? You said you watched this person do a factory reset, but did they remove their Google account first? If not, then the phone maybe locked to the previous ownets account...

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you had to wait 24, and 72 hours to be able to logon again to your google Account. **So apparently Google have warn you several times before block your IP (i think).**

Concretely, some information is missing in your tracking subject, namely the types of protections you have set up on your Google Account (confirmation email, confirmation SMS, secret key by Google Authentificator, etc).

It also lacks the essential information to know what the exact error message Google is displaying on the screen.

**In your security center on your phone connected to your Google Account, do you have any alert related to your problem? This famous Google security center is generally accessible via the phone's settings menu.**

**In yet another solution, the user has the ability to create special accesses for third-party applications (allow Outlook to access your Gmail account, allow access to your Google account through a Windows Phone).**

Maybe you could create a particular access for another type of device, Google will then provide you with an access code, it will want to write it down (without spaces), then enter it as a password to be able to access your Google Account without having you blocked again.

We hope this alternative will help you.